# Importing error on Magmi

Tags: php, sql, magmi

I usually import categories by first uploading to our server via FTP and then import it using MAGMI. However, I am getting the below error all of sudden

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Invalid argument in
>    - Trace not found"

Much appreciated if anyone could help me out.